# htaccess redirectMatch all files of a type except a certain one

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-alias

Say I have a web folder with:

```
/index.html
/assets/css/styles.css
/assets/images/logo.png
/something.html
/holdingpage.html
/finale.html
/folder/somefile.html
/else.html
/PDFs/something.pdf
```

I want to put in place an htaccess RedirectMatch for this to "catch" all the files that are html files except the `finale.html` and redirect to there.

What I have so far is:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ".*/$" "/finale.html"
```

Which correctly catches all folder without filenames (indexes).
What I need is to catch all the html but not that destination one.

```
RedirectMatch 302 ".*(\.html)$" "/finale.html" # This loops obviously.
```

So I tried to be more specific;

```
RedirectMatch 302 ".*!(finale.html)$" "/finale.html" 

RedirectMatch 302 ".*!(finale\.html)$" "/finale.html"
```

But this doesn't catch other files. Also by the looks of it I'd expect this to also catch assets and images.

I am trying to find a redirectMatch that finds every `.html` page that is **NOT** `finale.html` and redirect it to that page.

IT should be a redirectMatch and **NOT** a `rewriteCond` / `rewriteRule`. The user needs to see they're being redirected.

I imagine I want something like:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ".*((\.html) BUT NOT (finale.html))$" "/finale.html"
```

I have read the [Apache Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) but this doesn't really elaborate on this concept very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to match all `.html` files except for `/finale.html` (in the document root).

For example:

```
RedirectMatch 302 (?!^/finale\.html$)^/.+\.html$ /finale.html
```

> IT should be a redirectMatch and NOT a `rewriteCond` / `rewriteRule`. The user needs to see they're being redirected.

I'm not sure of the logic here. mod_rewrite can produce external redirects just the same as `RedirectMatch` and in fact, you should probably be using mod_rewrite here if you have existing mod_rewrite directives (primarily to avoid unexpected conflicts).

With mod_rewrite, you can do it similar to above with a negative lookahead. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (?!^finale\.html$)^.+\.html$ /finale.html [R=302,L]
```

Or, use an additional *condition* to make an exception for `finale.html`, instead of using a negative lookahead. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/finale\.html$
RewriteRule \.html$ /finale.html [R=302,L]
```

Which is arguably easier to read and possibly more efficient (the regex at least).

This matches all URLs that end in `.html`, except for `/finale.html` (exactly) and externally 302 redirects to `/finale.html`.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RedirectMatch 302 ".*!(finale.html)$" "/finale.html"
> ```

The `!` in the middle of the regex is a literal character here. The `!` *prefix-operator* is a feature of mod_rewrite. (It is a prefix-operator, not part of the regex syntax itself.

Comment: My concern with usual mod_rewrite is that the rewrite happens on the server so the browser won't see that it's a specific page.

Comment: @Martin mod_rewrite can do both external and internal redirects. The above is an external redirect (as denoted by the `R` flag), _exactly_ the same as `RedirectMatch`. A 302 response is sent back to the browser and the browser issues a redirect for the new URL - changing the URL in the browser.

Comment: @Martin Note that if you do use mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`/`RewriteCond`) then this should go before any existing internal rewrites, nearer the top of the file.